# Retrofit get Response body in failure(RetrofitError error) - async call

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit 1.9 in a big project and must check some data from response header even if call is failed - to analyse request code for example. We already know structure for async calls:

```
    RestClient.get().asyncRequest(requestParams, new Callback<GenericResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void success(MyPojo pojo, Response response) {
         //we can use pojo object or use whole response

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
         //we can handle only error but NOT response

        }
    });
```

How can we analyse Response in both cases here?

One solution is to use `Profiler` when `RestAdapter` is created, smth like:

```
     RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()

           //other stuff

            .setProfiler(new Profiler() {
                @Override
                public Object beforeCall() {
                    return null;
                }        

                @Override
                public void afterCall(RequestInformation requestInfo, long elapsedTime, int statusCode, Object beforeCallData) {
                  //get what I need
                    }
                })
                .build();
```

But maybe there is another solution to get response in `failure()` method. Any advices wil be apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get response body retriving it from `RetrofitError`.

```
      @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

         //here you get your response
          Response response = error.getResponse();

         //use data from response
         int code = response.getStatus();
         List<Header> =  response.getHeaders();
         // ...

        }
```

Comment: yeah, it's up to you how to use it

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem

```
 RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()

           //other stuff

            .setProfiler(new Profiler() {
                @Override
                public Object beforeCall() {
                    return null;
                }        

                @Override
                public void afterCall(RequestInformation requestInfo, long elapsedTime, int statusCode, Object beforeCallData) {
                  //get what I need
                    }
                })
                 .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).build();
```

Now you can get the response

```
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
  String json =  new String(((TypedByteArray)error.getResponse().getBody()).getBytes());
    Log.v("failure", json.toString());
 }
```

Comment: I have this - it's ONLY  for logs, but if I need to handle somehow the response when `failure()` method is called ? )

Answer (score 0):

failure method in retrofit only tells the error occurred if want to see you can check that the arguments of error method in retrofit or you can call again the service if you want to call again when it comes to failure.